# add user billing information into woocommerce registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add most if not all billing information fields to the registration form in the my-account page of the store.

I have tried with plugins but the meta-data that its supposed to be correct its not being added. I have tried adding a new field with meta data name billing_address_1. the custom field shows in the registration page but wont save the data. I added this custom field with WP-Members plugin.

The reason I am doing this is that I want the new user to enter the normal registration info ( username, pass) but also fill all of the billing information at the same time.

Thank you

Comment: Storing user billing information is very risky. If you do not secure your database(s) properly, and have a good understanding of how hacking and servers work, you are liable for anything that can go wrong. ie: Someone stealing someone elses credit card details.

Comment: didnt mean payment billing information is just woocommerce user billing information such as Address, City, Postal code, Company Name